# htaccess 301 Redirect

Tags: mod-rewrite, redirect, url-rewriting

I'm trying to 301 redirect

> http://www.domain.com/page.html

to

> http://subdomain.domain.com/page.html

and tried:

```
redirect 301 /page.html http://subdomain.domain.com/page.html
```

The problem is both the domain and the subdomain are pointed to the same dir and that makes the redirect in a way that will never complete.

also tried with no success:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain.com$
RewriteRule ^page\.html$ "http\:\/\/subdomain\.domain\.com\/page\.html" [R=301,L]
```

Comment: so this is just for vanity then?...

Comment: Do you have mod_rewrite enabled? And did you wrote: RewriteEngine On, before these rules?

Comment: yes  mod_rewrite is enabled and I have RewriteEngine On.
In first case I think it just loops.

Comment: ...and in second case I think the rule works for folders only?

Comment: check apache access log, so see if you really have redirect loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok...I figured this out - the second case works - just needs to be placed right after RewriteEngine On:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain.com$

RewriteRule ^page.html$ http://subdomain.domain.com/page.html [R=301,L]
```

and this could be used for multiple rules under one condition:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)?domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [S=2]

RewriteRule ^page.html$ http://subdomain.domain.com/page.html [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^page-2.html$ http://subdomain.domain.com/page-2.html [R=301,L]
```