# Redirect URL from https://www.oldweb.example/Vidz to https://www.newweb.example/Vidz

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
Redirect 301 /Vidz https://www.oldweb.example/Vidz
Redirect 301 /Vidz https://www.oldweb.example/Helium
```

Above is my code on. htaccess, and it is not working according to what it needed to be.

Right now, my site's pages namely `https://www.oldweb.example/Vidz` and the other one redirects on to `https://www.newweb.example`. What I would like to happen is for them to redirect to their respective new links which will be mentioned below.

`https://www.oldweb.example/Vidz` must be redirected to `https://www.newweb.example/Vidz` As well as 
`https://www.oldweb.example/Helium` must be redirected to `https://www.newweb.example/Helium`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [htaccess 301 Redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6192863/htaccess-301-redirect)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on [webmasters.se]